# É possivel adicionar sitios pessoais ao autocomplete do google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Queria utilizar a pesquisa das moradas do google mas também queria introduzir umas áreas pessoais.
Na `div` que é gerada pelo google consigo adicionar os campos que quero, mas não consigo criar uma função no `click` pois deve existir algo na api do google que bloqueia o `click`.
Abaixo o código que utilizei para adicionar à pesquisa:

```
   $(".pac-container").append('<div id="areasearch' + e + '" class="pac-item areasearch" style="display:none" onclick="clickOneAreaLocalizar(\'' + $(this).text() + '\')"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-areas"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched"></span>' + $(this).text() + '</span> <span>Area</span></div>');
```

Resultado:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código para adicionar a pesquisa à input:

```
   var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('TextBoxPesquisaMaps')); 

 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input),  { types: ['geocode'] });

// Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
// pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function () { 
            var places = searchBox.getPlace(); 

            // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            bounds.extend(places.geometry.location);
            localizarMaisProximo(places.geometry.location);

            map.fitBounds(bounds); 

 });
```

Fiz este exemplo para perceber melhor.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9rt3t2y/)
quando carregar no qwerty faz um alerta.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isto?
Obrigado.

Comment: Lendo a documentação ele não fala nada que dê para adicionar locais próprios, por mais que vc adiciona na marra o local no combobox, ele não possui os dados que o mapa precisa para marcar. Acho que no momento não é possível.

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer se chama marcador personalizado (custom markers)
Você deve criar os marcadores e adiciona-los ao mapa, desta forma eles irão aparecer na caixa de busca também!

Vejas os links abaixo:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

Comment: Boa ideia!! mas fiquei com algumas dúvidas se funciona. 
Quando diz "Você deve criar os marcadores e adiciona-los ao mapa" é por código ou adicionar no mapa online do google , disponível para todos? 
Criei um exemplo em código e os marcos não me aparecem para poder selecionar.
https://jsfiddle.net/14hthctd/

Comment: É por código, pela API JS do Maps, mas só vai aparecer no seu site...Se quiser adicionar para todos que usam o Maps, basta seguir este artigo: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846

Comment: A ideia é criar por código para ser dinâmico. 
Vou tentar fazer mais uns testes, mas o primeiro não resultou :/